# BST: print tree in sorted order using another key

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have next structures code in C for my binary tree:

```
struct student
{
    int studentID;
    char lastName[MAX_LENGTH];
    char firstName[MAX_LENGTH];
    float amount;
};

struct node
{
    struct student* record;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};
```

Records are inserted to the tree using studentID field as a key. When I'm printing the tree in order of studentID all is fine. But I want to print the SAME tree in order of lastName field.

I have only one idea: copy tree to array, sort array and display array.

Is there is any another solution?

Comment: You should try inserting records based on lastName, then you can get in-order traversal in terms of lastName field of student.

Comment: sort as array of pointer(struct student*).

Comment: An alternative would be to create an additional field `struct node *equal;` and put all equal records there. Then you can simply create an additional tree with `lastName` being your key and traverse the tree getting a sorted list. After all, you can have multiple keys with your data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build and maintain multiple binary search trees in parallel, optionally folding them into a single multi-indexed data structure:

```
struct node {
    struct student *record;
    struct node *left_by_id, *right_by_id,
                *left_by_name, *right_by_name;
};
```

Obviously, all the BST operations have to be modified for this to work: e.g. to insert a new `struct student*`, you must tie a single `node` into two trees.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index for lastName. You can use another BST which will store a lastName as key and a pointer to the corresponding node in your original BST.

```
struct indexNode {
    char lastName[MAX_LENGTH]
    struct node* originalNode;
};
```

You can go on inserting into this tree while inserting data in original tree.

This way you will have to spend `O(log n)` space to store extra index tree but will reduce your time for searching based on lastName to `O(log n)`. Also, practically you will be storing only a key and pointer to a node for each element.